# Unable to add a reference to unit test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I am setting up a unit test bench and as an example exercise created a simple calculator. I'd like to develop test cases for it. When I try to add the project reference to the unit test project an error "Enable to add a reference to project 'Calculator'" appears. No reason or corrective action is provided

Initially I thought the reason was because developer mode was not enabled on my computer. But the problem persists with developer mode on also.

Comment: is there a way I can add a screenshot to better show this ?

Comment: Are you saying `Calculator` is your unit test project? If not, why are you trying to add your unit test project as a reference to your other project? It should be the other way around. Adding more information about what your project types are, what the target platforms are, etc. will help people answer your question. Also, some clarity on what exactly you're doing? Which project you're trying to add as a reference to which project. You can add screenshots when you get more rep.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. I created a unit test project in .net instead of universal windows application and it worked